How to use React Testing Library with React Native Google Mobile Ads
I have installed React Native Google Mobile Ads and am able to test it successfully on my Android emulator.
However, when I try to run tests using testing-library, I receive the error:
Test suite failed to run
Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNGoogleMobileAdsModule' could not be found.

The issue occurs when I import my banner component which has the Mobile Ads library import. I understand how to show the banner conditionally when the NODE_ENV !== "test", but I don't know how to keep it from being imported entirely.
I am unable to test my components that have an ad integrated otherwise.
Thanks!

If you don’t need the lib in your tests, you can just mock out the whole thing in jest.setup file.

@johnhaup Sorry, I'm not clear on how to do that. How do I mock a component that is part of the component that I'm testing?
